# How to draw the regression tree correctly when clustering using R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I get stuck when trying to build a model.
I want to class the dataset freeny into 10 subsets by year.

`data(freeny)`

```
options(digits=2)
 year<-as.integer(rownames(freeny))
 freeny<-cbind(freeny,year)
 freeny = freeny[sample(1:nrow(freeny),length(1:nrow(freeny))),1:ncol(freeny)]
 freenyValues= freeny[,1:5]
 freenyTargets=decodeClassLabels(freeny[,6])
 freeny = splitForTrainingAndTest(freenyValues,freenyTargets,ratio=0.15)
 km<-kmeans(freeny$inputsTrain,10,iter.max = 100, nstart = 5)
 kclust=km$cluster
 library(tree)
 kclust=as.factor(kclust)
 mdp=cbind(freeny$inputsTrain,kclust)
 mdp<-data.frame(mdp)
 mdp.tr=tree(kclust~.,mdp)
```

but the result is that the tree only has 5 terminal nodes.It should be 10 terminal nodes because I divide into 10 clusters by kmeans. What's wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I delete the argument nstart but still only the regression tree only has several terminal nodes not all.

Answer (score 0):

No. It shouldn't. `tree` is an algorithm that tries to fit a tree given predictor and response, and stops if

> the terminal nodes are too small or too few to be split.

(manual page). Try adjusting the `minsize` parameter (see `?tree.control`).

> minsize: The smallest allowed node size: a weighted quantity. The
>             default is 10.

I think the following will do what is intended:

```
mdp.tr=tree(kclust~.,mdp, minsize= 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And I was just watching the manual page. I've tried your advice, but still not all the terminal nodes but few more than mdp.tr=tree(kclust~.,mdp)

Comment: Well, kmeans is agglomerative and does not produce a tree, so a tree is not an inherent property of this type of clustering. Thus, you don't have the guarantee of finding a perfectly fitting tree.

Comment: Then how can I make predictions by cluster analysis using R?

Comment: After I have finished cluster analysis, then how do I what principle do the result follows?Then, I input some new data to knew which cluster the new data belong to.

Comment: You can always calculate the distance of the new vector to cluster centers given in `kmeans$centers`. If `v` is the new vector, you can do `which.min( sapply( 1:10, function( x ) sum( ( v - km$centers[x,])^2 ) ) )` to find out in which cluster this point is. As for the principle, read how kmeans algorithm work.